# version `GLIBC_2.29' not found when using tflite-runtime

Tags: python, tensorflow, glibc, tensorflow-lite, ubuntu-20.04

I'm using the [official Python docker images](https://hub.docker.com/_/python) to deploy my project to an ARM-based Azure Virtual Machine. Here are the VM specifications:

- Architecture: aarch64 ([Standard_D4plds_v5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/dplsv5-dpldsv5-series#dpldsv5-series))
- OS: Ubuntu 20.04
- vCPU: 4
- RAM: 8GB

I'm using `tflite-runtime` library (v**2.5.0**) and **python 3.8.10** to run a *.tflite* model. However, after the build, when I run the container, it throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./app.py", line 17, in <module>
    from hpstate import HPStatePreprocessor, HPStateLiteModel, Timer
  File "/usr/src/app/hpstate.py", line 6, in <module>
    import tflite_runtime.interpreter as tflite
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tflite_runtime/interpreter.py", line 36, in <module>
    from tflite_runtime import _pywrap_tensorflow_interpreter_wrapper as _interpreter_wrapper
ImportError: /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tflite_runtime/_pywrap_tensorflow_interpreter_wrapper.cpython-38-aarch64-linux-gnu.so)
```

I tried different images such as slim, buster, and slim-buster, but no success.

It seems that the current GLIBC installed on the machine is 2.31:

`$ sudo apt-cache policy libc6`

```
  Installed: 2.31-0ubuntu9.9
  Candidate: 2.31-0ubuntu9.9
  Version table:
 *** 2.31-0ubuntu9.9 500
        500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/main arm64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.31-0ubuntu9.7 500
        500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/main arm64 Packages
     2.31-0ubuntu9 500
        500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/main arm64 Packages
```

Another thing I tried was to use a more recent python version (**3.9.14**), which is supported by `tflite-runtime` together with a more recent `tflite-runtime` version (**>=2.7.0**), and in that scenario, I get the following error when calling `interpreter.allocate_tensors()` :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/src/app/./app.py", line 188, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/src/app/./app.py", line 120, in main
    model = HPStateLiteModel(model_path=MODEL_FILE_PATH)
  File "/usr/src/app/hpstate.py", line 98, in __init__
    self._initialize_model(model_path)
  File "/usr/src/app/hpstate.py", line 102, in _initialize_model
    interpreter.allocate_tensors()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tflite_runtime/interpreter.py", line 521, in allocate_tensors
    return self._interpreter.AllocateTensors()
RuntimeError: Select TensorFlow op(s), included in the given model, is(are) not supported by this interpreter. Make sure you apply/link the Flex delegate before inference. For the Android, it can be resolved by adding "org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-select-tf-ops" dependency. See instructions: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_selectNode number 7 (FlexRange) failed to prepare.
```

I got the same errors using another ARM-based VM (with the same spec.) with Ubuntu 18.04. The pre-installed GLIBC version installed on that machine was 2.28. Any idea how can fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are building your binary against *system* GLIBC-2.31, and are trying to run in a container with older GLIBC (Debian buster used GLIBC-2.28 as far as I can tell).

That doesn't work (as you've discovered).

Your best bet is to *build* your binaries *inside* a docker image you are targeting (or rather in a docker image based on the same OS release).

Comment: I used an official debian image (i.e., debian:buster-slim) instead of python images, which solved the problem.